# Will the Logical nullish Assignment or nullish coalescing evaluate the assigned value in a non null case?

Tags: javascript, nullish-coalescing

I want to understand if my use case will benefit from the logical nullish assignment operator.

I'm checking my database to see it some data exists, otherwise I fetch it from an API, however I don't want to fetch the data from the API if the data already exists in my database, I'm describing the scenario with some code below.

```js
let myData = await Database.getData(); // will return null if the data doesn't exist
myData ??= await fetch("API"); // does this API call get executed even if myData is non null?
```

Just to clarify, I'm wondering if the API call is executed, even though it might return the database data.

Does using nullish coalescing instead make a difference, for such a scenario ?

I'm aware that I can use several methods including `if-else` for such a case, however I want to understand if these operators will for in such a scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this API call get executed even if `myData` is non-null?

No, it **will not** be executed.

```
myData ??= await fetch("API")
```

is equivalent to

```
myData ?? (myData = await fetch("API"))
```

So, only if the first expression `myData` is nullish, the second assignment part runs.

```js
let value = "test"
value ??= null.toString() // doesn't throw error because it is not executed
console.log(value)

value = null
value ??= null.toString() // throws error
```

Answer (score 0):

The nullish coalescing `(??)` operator is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is `null` or `undefined`, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

The answer is no. [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although my question was directed in terms of whether the righ-hand-side operand runs, even though it might return the left hand side. This was clarified by @adiga s answer. i.e. No it doesn't run. 

Also, it seems the link is broken, I'm unable to open it.

Comment: updated the link. Great that you got your answer you can visit the link to understand the details of the operator.